# How to hit get and post method in same session in java

Tags: java, rest, api, automation

Need to write java code to hit restapi.

I am using a get API for authorization.
After authorization,i have to hit post method.
I am getting get request response as 200,but post method response in 401 unauthorized.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    getRequest();
    postRequest();
}

public static void getRequest() throws IOException {
    URL urlForGetRequest = new URL("https://****/ws/auth/login?usr_id=***&password=***");
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlForGetRequest.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
//    String cookiesHeader = connection.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");
   // connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", apiKeyVal);
 //  System.out.println(session);
 //   HttpSession session = connection.getSession();
    int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println(responseCode);

}

public static void postRequest() throws IOException {
    final String inboundshipment = InboundShipmentJsonCreator.json();

    URL obj = new URL("https://****/ws/integration/api/**");

    HttpURLConnection postConnection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    postConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    postConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    postConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    postConnection.setDoOutput(true);
//    postConnection.setRequestProperty("Set-Cookie", cookiesHeader);
    OutputStream os = postConnection.getOutputStream();
    os.write(inboundshipment.getBytes());
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    int responseCode = postConnection.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("POST Response Code :  " + responseCode);
    System.out.println("POST Response Message : " + postConnection.getResponseMessage());
    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) { //success
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            postConnection.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while ((inputLine = in .readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        } in .close();
        // print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());
    } else {
        System.out.println("POST NOT WORKED");
    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error would imply a need to authorize. If there is login information required try using "Basic authentication" if you have the required information for it.

[Http request with basic auth java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50679070/http-request-with-basic-auth-java)

or using your commented code, save your cookie information from the login request and add it to the post.